# How can we delete a duplicated element in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I'm trying to delete duplicate elements in an array.
I can filter the element out, but in the end the position of that element will only be replaced by `0`, and not disappear

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[6] = {1,2,3,3,8,5};
    int newArr[6] = {};
    int temp,i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(j = i+1; j <= 6; j++){
            if(arr[i] != arr[j]){
                newArr[i] = arr[i]; 
                break;
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        temp = j;
        i = temp-1;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++){
        printf("%d,", newArr[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is: `1,2,3,0,8,5`

Expected result: `1,2,3,8,5`

Comment: You cannot delete elements of an array in the sense of making the array shorter.  You can only change the values of the elements.  In particular, you can move the later elements forward by one position each, and keep a record of how many elements are occupied by real data.

Comment: The `for(j = i+1; j <= 6; j++){` loop should test `j < 6` — you can't use index 6 to access the array and expect anything good to happen.  The `else { continue; }` can be omitted; the loop will be continued just the same.

Comment: I have to use ```<=6``` in order to put the last element of ```arr``` to ```newArr```. Please, Look at the code below the second loop where I handle it. If i put ```< 6```, it'd be ```1,2,3,0,8,0```

Comment: You must not use `j <= 6` because when `j` is `6`, you will compare `if (arr[i] != arr[j])` and `arr[j]` (aka `arr[6]`) is out of bounds of your array and you cannot tell what value you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. No need to create a new array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[6] = {1,2,3,3,8,5};
    int temp,i,j, size = 6;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){

        for(j = i+1; j < size; j++){

            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                for(int k = j; k < size; k++){
                    arr[k] = arr[k+1];   
                }
                size--;
                j--;

            }    
        }
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){
        printf("%d,",  arr[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect as `for(j = i+1; j <= 6; j++)` is at one point referring to 7th element which doesn't even exist.

Now comes the algorithm/method to use:

1. Sort the array first (you have chosen array as example `arr` which might mislead you.
2. Traverse the array and look for changes.

Do the sorting using some sort mechanism like merge sort or quicksort and here is the change detection mechanism in the sorted array where the duplicate element will be marked as **0**.

```
 int index=0;
 int change_detector = INT_MAX; //a macro - google it             
 unsigned int siz = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); //arr represents sorted array

 for(;index<siz;index++)
 {
    if(arr[index] != change_detector)
    {
      change_detector = arr[index];
    }
    else
    {
      arr[index]=0;          //marking the duplicate element as 0
    }
 }
 //print the array to check the result
```

Comment: Note that sorting the array will reorder the last two elements — the 8 and the 5.  It is not clear that it is acceptable to do that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I didn't pay attention to this part.

Comment: Thank Agrudge, I'll check your code. I've fixed my code and posted it here. Also, no need to sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

So you should probably realize first of all that arrays are a part of contiguous memory allocation and hence cannot be manipulated much aside from declaring a new array and deleting the entire array. Given a large enough array, what you really want to do is utilize counting sort to find out which all elements exist in an array, and then create a new array to transfer over these elements to it. It's a convenient little solution that works in O(n) time

Comment: That's nice. Thanks Kaustubh. I'll check that

Answer (score 0):

Since the size of your array is fixed, you have only two aspects of the array to change, (1) the contents of the array; and (2) your count of the number of elements it contains. In your case when removing duplicate values, you can overwrite the duplicate address with the remaining contents of the array, effectively shifting each element down by one (that changes the contents). To complete the process, you must subtract one from your count of the elements in the array to indicate it contains one less stored element than it did.

You can loop shifting all elements down, or `string.h` provides the `memmove()` function that can handle shifting the remaining elements. (you cannot use `memcpy()` where the source and destination overlap -- if copying within the same array -- they do). `memmove()` can be used when source and destination overlap. Using `memmove()` rather than looping element by element will be faster for larger arrays (it will shift more than one element at a time)

If you are just simulating removing elements from your array, there isn't really a need for a `newArray`, just shift within `arr`. Putting that together, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 8, 8 },   /* array */
        n = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;               /* number of elements */

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {               /* loop over elements */
        int j = i;                              /* initialize j = i */
        while (j < n && arr[j] == arr[j-1])     /* scan forward while current == prev */
            j++;                                /* increment until difference or end */
        if (j != i) {                           /* if duplicates found */
            if (j + 1 < n) {                        /* if not last elem */
                memmove (&arr[i], &arr[j],          /* move rest to current */
                        (n - j - 1) * sizeof *arr); /* (move total bytes) */
                n -= j - i;                         /* subtract removed elem from n */
            }
            else    /* last element */
                n = i;                              /* set n to current index */
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {               /* loop over modified array */
        printf (k ? ",%d" : "%d", arr[k]);      /* output elements */
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

(**note:** the array was updated to contain multiple adjacent duplicates (and triplicates), and the array must be in sort-order or the duplicated elements must be adjacent to one another for the above routine)

When using `memmove()` to move elements, you have to move the total number of bytes that make up that number of elements. For example to move two *integer* elements in your array, you must move `2 * sizeof *arr` bytes.

**Example Use/Output**

Removing duplicate elements from `{ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 8, 8 }` results in:

```
$ ./bin/arr_del_elem
1,2,3,4,8
```

or for a bit more interesting removal, use:

```
    int arr[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
                5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9 },   /* array */
```

**Result**

```
$ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

There are many ways to approach the process, this is just one.